# error in stored procedure syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getNumbers
(
@dName VARCHAR(20),
@iNum INT OUTPUT,
@sNum INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
@iNum=SELECT count(i.ID) FROM instructor WHERE dept_name=@dName
@sNum=SELECT count(s.ID) FROM student AS s WHERE dept_name=@dName
END
```

Here is my first attempt at making a stored procedure. I keep getting an error in syntax at the line: @dName VARCHAR(20),

I have looked at other problems and tried their solutions but nothing works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it MSSQL ? If so you don't need to use brackets and you should use following syntax to assign variables:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getNumbers
@dName VARCHAR(20),
@iNum INT OUTPUT,
@sNum INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @iNum=count(i.ID) FROM instructor WHERE dept_name=@dName;
SELECT @sNum=count(s.ID) FROM student AS s WHERE dept_name=@dName;
END
```

If you do it in MYSql

```
DELIMITER $$     
CREATE PROCEDURE getNumbers(
    IN dName VARCHAR(20),
    OUT iNum INT,
    OUT sNum INT)
    BEGIN
    SELECT count(i.ID)  INTO iNum FROM instructor WHERE dept_name=dName;
    SELECT count(s.ID) INTO sNum FROM student AS s WHERE dept_name=dName;
    END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this form:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getNumbers
@dName VARCHAR(20),
@iNum INT OUTPUT,
@sNum INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
```

Comment: sql server? Do you have anything before in this script?

Comment: That is the entire "query"